# Зациклить воспроизведения звука в chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5

есть подключенный файл звука через html5.

```
<audio  loop controls  id="rain_audio">
         <source src="audio/rain.mp3">
</audio>

let audioRain = document.getElementById('rain_audio');

audioRain.addEventListener('pause', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
```

Пытаюсь зациклить воспроизведения звука, в firefoxe все работает в chrome нет.
Так же почему то не работает событие ended в chrome, но когда звук доигрывается то срабатывает событие pause.

Comment: Там срабатывает событие `audio.onended` - просто запускайте заново, когда оно наступает, примерно так: `audio.onended=function(){this.play();};`

Comment: Фактически, в этом коде зацикливание задаётся двумя способами одновременно. Достаточно атрибута **loop** внутри тега **audio**. У меня зацикливается и в chrome и в firefoxe, так же везде зацикливается, когда я оставляю только **loop**.

Comment: В этом и странность у меня не зацикливается в chrome

Comment: Может консоль что-то пишет?